# OpenGL texture unit bindings - Why is a single texture mapped to both texture units when each are individually assigned?

Tags: opengl, texture

I am using NVIDIA Nsight to debug my OpenGL state. In the screenshots below:

- I generate a single texture with the ID `10`.
- I activate `GL_TEXTURE0` and bind texture `10` to that texture unit.
- I generate a single texture with the ID `11`.
- I activate `GL_TEXTURE1` and bind texture `11` to that texture unit.

When I view the API inspector, I see that texture `11` is bound to both `unit 0` and `unit 1`, which I presume is `GL_TEXTURE0` and `GL_TEXTURE1`.

Am I misunderstanding something about how texture units work in OpenGL? This is not the behavior I would expect.

[image: Events tab]

[image: API Inspector, Textures]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. I feel pretty silly. When I set `glActiveTexture` it primes the OpenGL context to set the active texture for **all** subsequence texture binds. Thus the bind at line 66 overwrites it. I solved this by setting `GL_TEXTURE0` as my 'reset' texture and setting `glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` when I am done binding a texture unit.